# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') (CryptoJS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cryptojs

I am studying cryptography and network security and i want to write code in js using CryptoJS API to peform AES Encryption and Decryption but i keep getting this error. I have seen a question just like me but they said change plaintext to string and it will work, and it actually work with them but not with me. I'm so confuse cus I think nothing can go wrong with this code but again pls help me.

This is the error:

[image: error]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AES Encryption Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Function to generate a random encryption key
      function generateKey() {
        return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(32); // 32 bytes = 256 bits key size
      }

      // Function to encrypt plaintext using AES cipher
      function encryptAES(plaintext, key) {
        const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key);
        return encrypted.toString();
      }

      // Function to decrypt ciphertext using AES cipher
      function decryptAES(ciphertext, key) {
        const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key);
        return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      }

      // Usage example
      var plaintext = "Hello, World!";
      const key = generateKey();

      console.log('Plaintext:', plaintext);

      const ciphertext = encryptAES(plaintext, key);
      console.log('Ciphertext:', ciphertext);

      const decryptedText = decryptAES(ciphertext, key);
      console.log('Decrypted Text:', decryptedText);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It would be so great if you guys explain to me how could it happen, thank you!

Comment: The specification of the IV is missing, since CryptoJS uses CBC by default.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify the initialization vector, the IV. Earlier versions of CryptJS apparently used a default of all zeroes, but according to the documentation you now have to supply one. Try something like:

```
// Keep track of it together with the key and pass it to the encrypt (and decrypt) functions
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
...
// Pass it to the encrypt (and decrypt) functions
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {iv: iv});
```

Comment: they should ideally just make the type to require `iv` since its still marked as optional still